# How/when to use expressions instead of returns in rust

Tags: rust, return, match, expression

I'm doing this advent of code in rust to learn it (started today with the rust book too since the language is becoming more interesting to me) and I'm having some doubts as of how to comply with rust style.

Just read in the book that in rust is more idiomatic to use an expression at the end of a function than a return statement, so I've been going through these past days challenges and refactoring them for this but I have some doubts.

First the commits where I change it from returns to expressions:

1. https://github.com/nerock/AdventOfCode2022/commit/db9649760b18b92bf56de6586791285522caf2b4
2. https://github.com/nerock/AdventOfCode2022/commit/b98b68c0fa8c7df0dcdba14eb642400468781084

If you look at `day1.rs` method `get_top_three`, I've modified it where I create a variable, and I assign it in an `if, else if, else` but my initial idea was to not have the `else` at all and have something like

```
if current > first {
    (current, first, second);
} else if current > second {
    top_three = (first, current, second);
} else if current > third {
    top_three = (first, second, current);
}

(first, second, third)
```

would this be possible in some way and maybe better? I've gotten used to avoid having an `else` expression and just returning the "default" result but maybe this is not the way in rust.

Besides this I'm still not sure when to use `match` in place of `if`, so if any of you look at my code and has some comments about my uses (or anything else to be honest) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want an open-ended code review, there is a dedicated site for it: [codereview.se]. Such questions are too unspecific here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but I disagree, the main part is indeed a concrete question about how to use a expression instead of a return, but besides that question I just mention that if someone has comments about my rust code would be helpful, but not mainly asking for a review

Comment: @ner0ck Because it's stackoverflow policy to ask a single question per post ;) if we vote to close a question, 'asks multiple questions at once' is even one of the official reasons we can enter. It has to do with the purpose of stackoverflow - it is meant as a huge Q&A for other people to search. And if you ask multiple questions or ask for personal code review, that's not much use for other people. As other people mentioned, codereview is the page for that.

Comment: People also didn't mention it yet, but linking to external code is also discouraged on stackoverflow. Questions on SO should be self-contained. For more info, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Rust-specific MRE tips](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info). Just imagine your post from my perspective: I haven't done AoC day1 yet, and I have no idea what you are talking about in this question. I would love to give you tips, but without visiting the links (which again, is discouraged) I have absolutely no clue what's going on.

Comment: There's no point at refactoring to avoid `return` in the middle of the function (there's a reason it's available), but you can just use the `if` as the return expression.

Comment: And BTW, I'd use a `match` on `(elf_move, player_move)` instead of a series of `if`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a lot of missing context and guessing, I assume that your question is as follows.

You had the code:

```rust
fn get_top_three(current: i32, first: i32, second: i32, third: i32) -> (i32, i32, i32) {
    if current > first {
        return (current, first, second);
    } else if current > second {
        return (first, current, second);
    } else if current > third {
        return (first, second, current);
    }

    (first, second, third)
}
```

And you heard that it's better to not do `return`, so you refactored it to:

```rust
fn get_top_three(current: i32, first: i32, second: i32, third: i32) -> (i32, i32, i32) {
    let top_three: (i32, i32, i32);

    if current > first {
        top_three = (current, first, second);
    } else if current > second {
        top_three = (first, current, second);
    } else if current > third {
        top_three = (first, second, current);
    } else {
        top_three = (first, second, third)
    }

    top_three
}
```

And now your question is, is this better? If yes, why? What could you do differently?

---

The answer is: Yes and no. What you are missing is that **everything** can be used as a return expression. Including, and very important in this case, `if` statements.

So you can rewrite the entire function like this:

```rust
fn get_top_three(current: i32, first: i32, second: i32, third: i32) -> (i32, i32, i32) {
    if current > first {
        (current, first, second)
    } else if current > second {
        (first, current, second)
    } else if current > third {
        (first, second, current)
    } else {
        (first, second, third)
    }
}
```

And maybe with this in mind, you now realize how powerful those expressions really are :)

So why does this work?

**Everything** in Rust has a value. For example:

- Every block of code in a `{}` has a value:

  ```rust
  fn main() {
      let x = {
          let y = 10;
          y
      };
      println!("{}", x);
  }
  ```

  ```
  10
  ```
- Every `if`-`else` has a value:

  ```
  fn main() {
      let condition = false;
      let y = if condition { 5 } else { 15 };
      println!("{}", y);
  }
  ```

  ```
  15
  ```

And so on. Basically every block of code that is surrounded by `{}` has a value, and you can set its value by a value expression in its last line. Just like at the end of a function. And you can assign its value directly to a variable, or forward it to its surrounding code block (like the way I refactored your code, where the value of the `if` block gets directly forwarded to the function).

**That** is what makes this language feature so powerful.

Comment: Thanks a lot i had read about expressions but wasn't that clear to me yet, now it is